# what is difference between insmod modules and rpm packages in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I came across the insmod and rpm usages in my project. 
Could you please explain in details what is difference between `insmod` modules and `rpm` packages in Linux ?

```
insmod <module.ko>
rpm -ivh <rpm_name>
```

which type of files module and package contains?

Answer (score 1):

insmod is used to load(or insert) a kernel module. it can't be used to install user space application.
rpm is used to install an application on linux with an rpm package which contains applications, config files and other files. If the rpm package contains a kernel module, then rpm will call insmod to load(or insert) the kernel module.

Comment: What's the -1 for?

Comment: `insmod` doesn't *install* a module, it **inserts** (**loads**) already installed kernel module into the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `insmod` is for kernel space and `rpm` is for user space. This is only roughly correct but a good starting point. Following is some more rough description.

`insmod` loads a kernel module, thereby enhancing kernel functionality. For example, using `insmod` one can load driver for a specific hardware, allowing kernel to deal with that hardware.

`rpm` is package manager which is used to install programs - usually user space applications like vim or firefox browser. It is more like `apt` or `pacman`.

Comment: `rpm` is not like `apt` — rather like `dpkg`. `apt` is more similar to e.g. `yum`. Also, kernel image packages are also RPM, and some drivers are _installed_ (as opposed to loaded) also as RPM packages.

Comment: Agree. But that's why it's called rough description. If the question is about insmod vs rpm, further details will only help to confuse.